# How to add Query Hints to spring data jpa querydsl queries?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I'm using Spring Data JPA 1.7.1

I was trying pass query hints (e.g. for Hibernate query caching) to queries when using the querydsl methods of the standard Spring Data repositories, as defined in the `QueryDslPredicateExecutor` interface, e.g. `findOne(Predicate predicate)`, `findAll(Predicate predicate)` etc.

I figured that they can be set by overriding the methods in `QueryDslPredicateExecutor` (in my repository interface or an intermediate interface) and adding the `QueryHints` annotation, but since I cannot find this documented anywhere I was wondering if this is the recommended way of doing it.

Here is an example:

```
public interface MyEntityRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, Integer>, CacheableQueryDslPredicateExecutor<MyEntity> {

    @QueryHints(value = {
            @QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheable", value = "true"),
            @QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheMode", value = "NORMAL"),
            @QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheRegion", value = "myCacheRegion")
    })
    Iterable<T> findAll(Predicate predicate);

}
```

Comment: Are you sure about the version? Support for that was added via [DATAJPA-574](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-574) in 1.7.0.RC1. `QueryDslJpaRepository.createQuery(…)` should actually apply those hints.

Comment: What I posted above actually works. I just wanted to know if it's the correct usage, because I can't find it documented anywhere, relating to querydsl. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

This is the recommended and correct way of doing it, see documentation for 1.7.1:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.query-hints

Comment: Yes I have seen that, but that only mentions custom queries, not related to querydsl. My question was about querydsl queries. I have assumed it can be used as I posted (by overriding the standard methods).